# Rstudio multiline commenting shortcut does not do anything

Tags: r, rstudio

As the title says, I normally use `ctrl` + `shift` + `c` to comment out multiple lines of code in Rstudio. It no longer works (nothing happens when I use the above shortcut).

I am using Rstudio version:
2022.02.3 Build 492

"Prairie Trillium" Release (1db809b8, 2022-05-20) for Windows

Session info:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.1 tools_4.1.1
```

I have had look in "Global options" but cannot see any setting relating to multiline commenting and in the "keyboard shortcuts help" section it still lists `ctrl` + `shift` + `c` as the correct shortcut. Anyone know what my issue could be?

Comment: Could it be another tool in Windows that uses the same combination? (Snagit, some clipboard manager...)

Comment: I guess that could be a possibility. I haven't installed anything new recently and it still occurs when Rstudio is the only program I have open.

Comment: I had similar issues that turned out to be caused by AMD Radeon Software shortcuts. `ctrl`+ `shift` + `c` is "toggle camera on/off" by default there.

Comment: @Mikko Marttila Thank you, that was it! must have kicked in after AMD software updated. Under settings -> hot keys turn off hot keys short cuts in AMD Radeon Software and the issue was solved.